# WooCommerce costum meta_key

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, meta-key

I would like to add a custom `meta_key` value to each WooCommerce product It will be the Discount rate :

```
_discount_rate = ((_sale_price-_regular_price_)/(_regular_price)*100)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add a filter to WooCommerce function `woocommerce_process_product_meta` Something like:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'mytheme_product_save_discountrate');

function mytheme_product_save_discountrate($post_id) {

    if (get_post_meta($post_id, "_sale_price")) {

        $regular_price = get_post_meta($post_id, "_regular_price");
        $sale_price = get_post_meta($post_id, "_sale_price");

        $discount_rate = ($sale_price - $regular_price) / $regular_price * 100);

        update_post_meta($post_id, '_discount_rate', $discount_rate);
    }
}
```

I'm just not sure how I can retrieve the regular and sale prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WooCommerce has an inbuilt methods to get the price
>   `get_regular_price()` and `get_sale_price()`.

Here is the code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'mytheme_product_save_discountrate', 999); //<-- check the priority

function mytheme_product_save_discountrate($post_id) {

    $_product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $_product->get_sale_price();
//    $_product->get_price();

    if (!empty($sale_price)) {
        $discount_rate = (($sale_price - $regular_price) / ($regular_price)) * 100; //replace it with your own logic
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_discount_rate', $discount_rate);
    }
}
```

*Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin PHP files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great thank! Is there a way to apply it to products already in db?

Comment: @Jeremaya456853: you want to add apply `_discount_rate` to all the existing products? and you have simple product or variable product?

Comment: external products (term_id = 5)

Comment: all the products which belongs to term = 5?